# Angular routeProvider vs UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, angular

Can you use Angular routeProvider with Salesforce? I am having trouble rendering views that are located in the static resources zip. Would it be better to use UI Router?

Answer (score 1):

The approach to handling static resources in the [IssuesInGitHub](https://github.com/metadaddy-sfdc/IssuesInGitHub/blob/master/metadata/staticresources/github_app_js.resource) sample application is to reference the templates using:

```
templateUrl: '/resource/' + Date.now() + '/github_issues_html'
```

which ensures that the latest version of the static resource is referenced but stops the template being cached. The approach works fine with `$routeProvider`. So it is a good approach to start with.

With a bit more effort, if say the index page is a Visualforce page, you can set a field of a JavaScript object to the Visualforce expression `'{!$Resource.appzip}'` and add that object as an [Angular constant](https://force201.wordpress.com/2014/04/11/passing-platform-configuration-to-an-angularjs-app/) that you can then reference in the templateUrl:

```
templateUrl: Constants.zipPrefix + '/github_issues_html'
```

This ensures that the template static resources are cached and when a new version of the zip is deployed that the new version is moved to and cached.

Comment: what are your thoughts on using UI-Router to render states as pages? This seem like it would be nice since it does not matter if I am routing through the URL

Comment: @WesW I've no experience of UI-Router so am not in a position to compare the two. For the Angular code I've written $routeProvider has worked OK. If you need [UI-router](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023763/angularjs-difference-between-angular-route-and-angular-ui-router) use it but otherwise [KISS](http://effectivesoftwaredesign.com/2013/08/05/simplicity-in-software-design-kiss-yagni-and-occams-razor/).

Comment: The example you referred to is using UI router instead of the standard routeProvider

Comment: @WesW Sure but AFAIK the `templateUrl` concept is the same.